# acts_as_geocodable validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When submitting a model that contains an error for `acts_as_geocodable` 3 of the same validation errors are getting displayed. Any thoughts as to whats going on here?

[image: acts_as_geocodable errors]

```
  create_table "skateparks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                                :null => false
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "locality"
    t.string   "region"
    t.string   "postal_code"
    t.string   "country"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.boolean  "indoor"
    t.boolean  "outdoor"
    t.string   "ownership"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.text     "website"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "delta",          :default => true,    :null => false
    t.integer  "square_footage"
    t.boolean  "restrooms"
    t.boolean  "lights"
    t.boolean  "skateshop"
    t.string   "cached_slug"
    t.string   "status",         :default => "draft", :null => false
    t.integer  "photos_count",   :default => 0
    t.integer  "comments_count", :default => 0
    t.integer  "ratings_count",  :default => 0
    t.integer  "lock_version",   :default => 0,       :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "builder_id"
    t.integer  "designer_id"
  end
```

Comment: No idea what's going on. If you add some relevant code to your question, maybe I will have an idea.

Comment: @Mikhail I added the table schema to my question. @Mischa Thanks for the snarky answer...

Comment: @Kyle, you are welcome. But, seriously, if you'd show the code of the `Skatepark` model, the controller method and the form that causes this, maybe I can help you.

Comment: what are the `keys` of the error messages you have?

Comment: @apneadiving `skatepark.errors.inspect` => `{:description=>["can't be blank"], :name=>["can't be blank"], :base=>["please provide a valid address", "please provide a valid address", "please provide a valid address"]}`

Comment: @Mischa I couldn't possibly post the entire model, controller and form on here but if you'd care to take a look at the project I have it hosted over at http://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web Also, sorry for the attitude in my previously reply. It's late and this thing has been aggravating me for a couple of hours now.

Comment: Ok weird, i don't know the source but I'd do skatepark.errors[:base].uniq!

Comment: @Kyle, you don't have to apologize for you attitude. I just think that when all you are asking is "I am using acts_as_geocoder and validations errors are shown three times instead of once. What's going on?", the chances of getting an answer are very slim...

I've been browsing your source and act_as_geocoder's source for a while, but I don't see anything strange. Sorry I couldn't help you.